Ubuntu 24.xx not starting on AMD Ryzen 7 5800U
I bought the AM06 Pro Mini-PC from Acemagic with an AMD Ryzen 7 5800U. And I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS and the latest 24.10. All have the similar behavior:
USB-Install-stick - grub menu:

"Try or Install Ubuntu" won't start properly - ends with a black screen
"Ubuntu (safe graphics)" starts and I can install the system
No matter I choose install drivers like "NVIDIA and so on ..." or not, the installed system ends with a black screen.

After switching off, I could grab dmesg (https://pastebin.com/K3Fv1Ti4) and syslog (https://pastebin.com/DiHvF5jT) files from the installed system.
Can you see anything, that is going wrong? Do you have any idea, how I can fix it?
Unfortunately, the SSH service isn't running at this moment, so I cannot try anything interactively. Everything I must do in a foreign booted environment.
When I shall send further information e.g. something from the BIOS settings, let me know. It's an AMI-Bios, that runs in UEFI-Bios mode.
Best regards and thank you in advance, Andreas

Install any Linux but Ubuntu/with gnome. Most of your second syslog trace shows Gnome errors or flaws in snap. What about Xubuntu (or Alpine if we are talking about embedded devices) ?. Software is a tool, and you won't use a hammer to get a nail out

Hm, I wrote a lot software using Gnome libraries in the past. But Gnome is just using the X server, this should be hardware independend. And with another framework I would change the hammer just by another hammer. I could install Fedora successfully now - with Gnome, but they just run it in Standard Graphic mode - without special drivers I guess.
Maybe I'll do a test with Kubuntu. But if I'm right and there are the problems with the graphics driver and wayland, it won't work either.

Ubuntu relies heavily on Gnome, which became very resource hungry. (Gnome 2 ran on an old Thinkpad T42 without issues - now its like MS-Windows) XFCE also uses GTK, but not the Gnome-shell (with Mutter) - so try a XFCE distro.

Okay, I don't know how to solve it with the current Ubuntu versions (24.04 LTS or 24.10 or 22.04 LTS).
I just tried the Pop! OS, this works quite well. It's also based on Ubuntu and uses Gnome. 
